# How do I pump up water pressure in my shower?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, water-pressure

I have a well system that generates approx 35 psi of flow to my shower. How can I pump up pressure to the shower?

Comment: PSI is pressure, flow is often measured in gallons per minute. We'd need to know the GPM coming off your well, shower, and perhaps a sink or two to give advice since the problem can be in different locations.

Comment: Depends on the pump, plumbing system pipe material and how high the pump has to lift the water from level in the well casing to the top of the house. Pressure stresses plumbing so do you want stronger spray action or more water flow through the head?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with new Shower head. You make have a low pressure model or it may just be clogged/hardwater build up.  If that doesn't work check your water filter it may be clogged and needs to be replaced. Many have a bypass so you can see if there is any difference. It is possible you have partially clogged pipes or your shower cartridge/valve  could be blocked with dirt in the screen.  You can replace the Pressure Switch with a 40/60 psi.